# Menu button constantly shaking on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

I made a portfolio site and there is a problem with the burger menu. It keeps on shaking. Not able to understand the reason. I am attaching the link to my website. Please check and do help me out. View the website in mobile screen.
I have used basic HTML, CSS, JS. For the typing animation, used typed.js

[Link to Website](https://biswajit-2600.github.io/Portfolio/)

I want the site to be as it is and the just the menu icon to stop shaking.

Comment: What do you mean by "just the menu icon to stop shaking". Also, please add your code to be able to help you.

Comment: changing position: fixed in header to sticky or absolute solve the issue but I can't found the reason why position fixed behaving like this.

Comment: yes @Nisha, it works fine thank you for the suggestion. Also, let me know if you get to know why fixed is acting odd.

Answer (score 0):

It is the header with position: fixed;
I tried

```
header{position: sticky;}
```

and works well

Comment: Yes, you are right it works fine. The constant shake is gone but I want the header to just be where it is when I scroll, and this feature no longer works. I mean, it's working on a PC but not on a mobile screen. Any further solution?

Comment: You sure? I open the website with iPhone and the header is fixed in top position